# Remove page number in blank even pages within the front matter

Tags: page-numbering, front-matter

In the front matter, is there any way to show blank pages without any headings or page numbers?

For example, if I have a preface which just fits in one odd page, I don't want the follwing blank even page to show anything.

I am using the `book` class.

Thanks.

Comment: `memoir` and KOMA-script classes have a simple interface for that. I think it is the default behaviour for KOMA.

Comment: Add `\usepackage{afterpage}` to your preamble and try with `\afterpage{\thispagestyle{empty}}\cleardoublepage`.

Comment: The `titlesec/titleps` package has a `clearempty` option that does exactly that in every empty page.

Comment: Try the `emptypage` package.

Comment: @Werner Where should I put the `\afterpage{\thispagestyle{empty}}\cleardoublepage` command?

Comment: @baister: At the end of your one-page preface.

Answer (score 4):

You can load the package `scrextend`. Then it is the default behaviour.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{preface}
\blindtext
\mainmatter
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

It is also possible to choose an other style for such pages using the package option `cleardoublepage=<pagestyle>` or using the macro

`\KOMAoptions{cleardoublepage=<pagestyle>}`

So you can use `plain` in the `\mainmatter` if you want:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{preface}
\blindtext
\mainmatter
\KOMAoptions{cleardoublepage=plain}
\chapter{Start}
\blindtext
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want that behavior in the whole document, simply load the package `emptypage`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum[1]

\mainmatter
\chapter{1}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{2}
\lipsum[1]

\backmatter
\chapter*{Conclusions}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter*{At the end}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

If instead, you want that behavior in the frontmatter, but not in the mainmatter, you can do the following.

Using the code from the `emptypage` package we define two commands, `\setempty` to print blank empty pages, and `\setnonempty` to print normal empty pages.

```
\makeatletter
\def\emptypage@emptypage{%
    \hbox{}%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \newpage%
    \if@twocolumn%
        \hbox{}%
        \newpage%
    \fi%
}
\let\oldcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage
\newcommand{\setempty}{%
  \def\cleardoublepage{%
      \clearpage%
      \if@twoside%
          \ifodd\c@page%
              % do nothing
          \else%
              \emptypage@emptypage%
          \fi%
      \fi%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\setnonempty}{%
  \let\cleardoublepage\oldcleardoublepage%
}
\makeatother
```

Here is a MWE that shows how it works.

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\def\emptypage@emptypage{%
    \hbox{}%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \newpage%
    \if@twocolumn%
        \hbox{}%
        \newpage%
    \fi%
}
\let\oldcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage
\newcommand{\setempty}{%
  \def\cleardoublepage{%
      \clearpage%
      \if@twoside%
          \ifodd\c@page%
              % do nothing
          \else%
              \emptypage@emptypage%
          \fi%
      \fi%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\setnonempty}{%
  \let\cleardoublepage\oldcleardoublepage%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\setempty
\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum[1]

\mainmatter
\setnonempty
\chapter{1}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{2}
\lipsum[1]

\backmatter
\setempty
\chapter*{Conclusions}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter*{At the end}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I found this to be the simplest solution:

```
\usepackage[clearempty]{titlesec}
```

Comment: work for me, thx